# Reading and writing into dropbox account without manual intervention

Tags: web-services, oauth, dropbox-api

I need to use dropbox as server storage. For that, I need my web app to talk to just one dropbox account (of my server) and bypass the Oauth. Is there some way I can read and write to  dropbox without any manual intervention (like authenticating). I just need to read and write into a single dropbox account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the OAuth flow once and save the resulting access token for future use. Once you have an authorized access token, you can make API calls without further user intervention.